# Yii2 Read Write splitting couldn't connect slave server in master slave configuration

Tags: yii2

Have done Master Slave configuration as per official Yii2 documentation. Below is actual configuration look like,

```
'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=1.1.1.1;dbname=master_db',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'enableSchemaCache' => true,
        'schemaCacheDuration' => 10,
        'schemaCache' => 'cache',
        'slaveConfig' => [
            'username' => 'slave_user',
            'password' => 'slave_password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'attributes' => [
                // use a smaller connection timeout
                PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 10,
            ],
            'enableSchemaCache' => true,
            'schemaCacheDuration' => 10,
            'schemaCache' => 'cache',
        ],
        'slaves' => [
            ['dsn' => 'mysql:host=2.2.2.2;dbname=slave_db']
        ],
    ],
```

It always connect master database even if slave server is up and reachable.

Surprisingly replacing current master config with slave one works, moreover if try to connect slave database from command line it get connected in a moment but unable to achieve same with above configuration.

Wondering if there is any parameters missing in configuration or any other way to get things working like ideal read write splitting?

Comment: What action triggers opening connection?

Comment: yii\db\Connection class has all connection related code. Initially it goes to find enabled slave server if any, then try to connect it through PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was resolved by adding connection class in the slaveConfig,

'class' => 'yii\db\Connection'